# How can I identify the position of a single element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a simple rating application, however, instead of all the circles turning green, I only want the selected circle to remain green.

```
$('#rating-container').click(function () {
    var element = $('#target');
    var container = $('#rating-container');
    var index = container.children().get(element);
    var foundElement = container.children().get(index);
    var jQueryObject = $(foundElement);
    jQueryObject.addClass('rating-chosen');
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="rating-container">
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div id="target" class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Codepen link below:

https://codepen.io/CasaDeOrellana/pen/JqqJxZ

Comment: Updated your pen. Check this. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLLXGY

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) with [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) like below. And you can find the index using the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method.

```js
$("#rating-container div").click(function(index, item) {
  $('#rating-container div').removeClass('rating-chosen'); // Comment (Delete) this line if you don't want to remove class from previous selection
  $(this).toggleClass('rating-chosen');
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: darkblue;
}

.rating-circle {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  border-radius: 1.1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.1em;
}

.rating-hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rating-chosen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rating-container">
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div id="target" class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I just used a slightly different approach:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".rating-circle").click(
    (e) => {
      event = e || window.event;
      var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

      $(".rating-circle").removeClass("rating-chosen");

      $("#" + target.id).addClass("rating-chosen");
    }
  )
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  color: darkblue;
}

.rating-circle {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  border-radius: 1.1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.1em;
}

.rating-hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rating-chosen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rating-container">
  <div class="rating-circle _1" id="1"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle _2" id="2"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle _3" id="3"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle _4" id="4"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle _5" id="5"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rating-circle").click(function() {
    // reset all
    $(this).parent().find('div').removeClass("rating-chosen");
    // Set selected
    $(this).addClass("rating-chosen");
  });
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enz5toyx/1/)

`$(this).index()` - Gives the index of the clicked circle

`$(this).toggleClass("rating-chosen");` - Toggles the class - adds class if it is not present, removes class if it is present.